# What are some good strategies/applications for viewing/analyzing metrics I have stored in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket full of plaintext metrics and want a way in which to analyze and view this data. One option I am considering is Amazon Athena, but I would like to consider the pros and cons of a few approaches.

Comment: What is the format of the files? CSV? Compressed? Is each file independent, or are similar types grouped by folder? How many files are there, and how big are they? Please edit your question to add more details rather than answering in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Athena is really good for adhoc analysis. If your file is in a format as supported by Athena  and if you want to run just few adhoc analysis. You can quickly get started with Athena.

If you want to make your adhoc analysis faster, create an external table over your existing files, consider running a Athena [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) query to transform your data to Avro / Parquet and partition / bucket your data as necessary.

If cost is not an issue, you can also look in to Redshift. See if its possible to execute redshift copy command on your files to import all these files in a Redshift DB. Use the appropriate sort keys and distribution keys to improve your query performance in Redshift.